# Access: How to create an update query from a calculated field

Tags: ms-access, sql-update, calculated-field

I'm very new to Access, so I'm sorry if this is a silly question.  I've searched extensively for the answer, but I may not be using the correct terms.

I have two tables tblStudents1213 and tblAttendance12-13. I've created a query that counts the total number of unexcused absences a student has.  I'd like to then take that calculated value and then create an update query which would update tblStudents1213.total_unexcused based according to the primary key which is a field called student_key.

Currently, I run my first query which counts the absences, I include the student_key field, export the table to an excel file, import that excel file as a new table, and then write an update query using SQL to update tblStudents1213.  I'm not very good with SQL either I'm afraid.

Thank you for any help you can offer!

**edit**

This is the code for the query I use to count the number of unexcused absences:

```
SELECT tblStudents1213.student_key, [tblAttendance12-13].excused_absence, Count([tblAttendance12-  13].ID) AS Total_Unexcused
FROM tblStudents1213 INNER JOIN [tblAttendance12-13] ON tblStudents1213.student_key =  [tblAttendance12-13].student_key
GROUP BY tblStudents1213.student_key, [tblAttendance12-13].excused_absence
HAVING ((([tblAttendance12-13].excused_absence)=3));
```

Sample Data:

tblAttendance12-13

```
ID    student_key    excused_absence
1        195797           3
2        195797           1
3        195797           2
4        195797           3
5        195797           3
```

tblStudents1213

```
student_key     grade     gender     total_unexcused
195797             8        1              
139722             9        2
492757             9        2
```

Primay key in tblStudents1213 is "student_key", which is also a foreign key in tblAttendance12-13 (one to many). Primary key in tblAttendance12-13 is "ID"

Comment: List the primary / foreign keys for the tables and some sample data (you probably don't need to include all the fields, but `StudentID`, `CountOfAbsences`, etc. are important)

Comment: By the way, you will probably have to use a Temp Table. Since Jet 4 (I believe?), you cannot use aggregation in an update query. Aggregation, in this case, being your `Count()`.

Comment: Added a bit more information, hopefully that helps.  Thank you so much for trying to help me out, I'm really quite new to this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So, for our first query, we want a `COUNT()` of all records where `excused_absence = 3`, and we can `GROUP BY` `Student_key` to achieve those results.

```
SELECT tblAttendence.Student_key,
 Count(*) AS CountOfexcused_absence 
INTO ExcusedTempTbl
FROM tblAttendence
WHERE (((tblAttendence.[excused_absence])=3))
GROUP BY tblAttendence.Student_key;
```

Because we can't use an aggregate query as a temp recordset, we can create a Temporary table to use to do just that. Each time you run the query, the table will be deleted and recreated.

Now we need to update `tblStudents`with the data.

```
UPDATE ExcusedTempTbl 
INNER JOIN tblStudents ON ExcusedTempTbl.Student_key = tblStudents.Student_key 
SET tblStudents.total_unexcused = [ExcusedTempTbl].[CountOfexcused_absence];
```